# React Native Android - How to set the logo icon in ToolBarAndroid?

Tags: react-native

I've copied a code for an AndroidToolBar from React Native's UIExplorer:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
            logo={require('image!launcher_icon')}
            navIcon={require('image!ic_menu_black_24dp')}
            onIconClicked={() => this.drawer.openDrawer()}
            style={styles.toolbar}
            title={title}
          />
```

But it seems like the **image!launcher_icon** and **image!ic_menu_black_24d**p are missing. I am getting a missing error:
[image]

It seems like some a system's baked-in  icon.

1. How can I use this icon?
2. How can I use my own png file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is old syntax. It has been changed in the recent versions.

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  logo={require('./ic_launcher_icon.png')}
  navIcon={require('./ic_menu_black.png')}
  onIconClicked={() => this.drawer.openDrawer()}
  style={styles.toolbar}
  title={title}
/>
```

Check out this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#content

Comment: So i need to add ic_launcher_icon.png manually as a file to my folder tree?

Comment: Yes. Previously you had to add it in xcode or android studio. Now you can just add it in your file tree. You can also use different resolutions by suffixing with 2x,3x etc. Check out this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content

Comment: Thanks! helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with updated syntax and define the correct path for image resource, I have made "images" folder inside "app" to store all my images at one place. You may skip them.

```
<ToolbarAndroid style ={{height:56, backgroundColor:'#e0e0e0'}}
                logo={require('./app/images/jd_home.png')}
                title={"MyApp"}
                actions={[{title: 'More', icon: require('./app/images/more.png'), show: 'always'},
                         {title: 'Settings', icon: require('./app/images/settings.png'), show: 'always'}]}
               />
```